# TCL: clock scan dd/mm/yy

Tags: linux, tcl

Is there any way to to allow "clock scan" work with date: dd/mm/yy?
I found it work only mm/dd/yy

To overcome this I had to swap between day & month but it's little bit ugly

Comment: Unless you use a very old Tcl (pre-8.5), `clock scan` has a -format option that lets you specify exactly what the input looks like.

Comment: Use new tcl version.
Is it possible maybe with a date command?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Schelte Bron's comment:

```
set d 31/12/22
clock format [clock scan $d]                   ;# => Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 EDT 2024
clock format [clock scan $d -format %d/%m/%y]  ;# => Sat Dec 31 00:00:00 EST 2022
```

Comment: It's kind of crazy that the 31st month of 2022 is July 2024. But, I suppose, it's equally as useful as "April 31 == May 1"

Comment: There are crazy cases that need that sort of thing, but I prefer `clock add` for timestamp arithmetic.